# Asigning Variables to a function - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created this bit of code to toggle on click. I'd like to expand this further. I currently have copied and pasted this for the number of times I require it. I was wondering what is the best way to Streamline this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('#ServiceTitle').click(ToolTip); 
    function ToolTip(){
        $("#tooltip").toggle();
    }
}(jQuery));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('#ServiceTitle2').click(ToolTip2); 
    function ToolTip(){
        $("#tooltip2").toggle();
    }
}(jQuery));
</script>

<div class="tb_text_wrap">
<p>Nationwide Broadband Network</p>
<h2><b>MULTISTREAM<span id="ServiceTitle" data-toggles=".tooltiptext1" class="Blocki">i</span></b></h2>
<div class="Bar">
<p id="ServiceStatus" class="BarBox Error">Maintenance Mode</p>
</div>
<p id="tooltip" class="tooltiptext1">Test text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Attached above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attributes are typically how you do it.

```js
$("[data-toggles]").on("click", function () {
  var selector = $(this).data("toggles");
  $(selector).toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-toggles=".foo1">AAAA</div>
<div class="foo1">AAAAAAAA Text</div>

<div data-toggles="#bar">BBBBBB</div>
<div id="bar">BBBBBB Text</div>
```

Other options can be based on HTML layout and select the child, sibling, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's worked perfectly on desktop and makes a lot of sense. Doesn't seem to work on mobile though?